# How to fix incorrect emacs C#-mode indentation for method braces

Tags: indentation, csharp-mode

My problem is that Emacs incorrectly indents the braces for C# methods, like this:

```
static string LOL()
    {

    }
```

then I have to manually correct it to

```
static string LOL()
{

}
```

I have read similar questions where the indentation is incorrect for if-statements and co. In my case the indentation works correctly. In spirit of those answers I have added these entries to my `init.el`

```
(defun my/c-mode-common-hook ()
  "Correct the expression indentation for c-style methods"
  (setq c-basic-offset 4)
  (c-set-offset 'substatement-open 0))

(use-package csharp-mode
  :mode "\\.cs\\'"
  :ensure t
  :defer t
  :init 
  (use-package omnisharp)
  (add-hook 'c-mode-common-hook #'my/c-mode-common-hook)
  :config
  (add-hook 'csharp-mode-hook 'omnisharp-mode)
  (add-hook 'after-init-hook 'global-company-mode)
  (company-omnisharp t))
```

How can I make Emacs use correct indentation for these braces?

Answer (score 1):

This is not an auto-indentation problem, but rather one of electric indentation.  To understand why, you must break down user input for this case into more steps, I'll demonstrate with an `if` example and `|` denoting the cursor:

```
if (42)| // RET
```

```
if (42)
| // auto-indent
```

```
if (42)
    | // {
```

```
if (42)
    {| // indent
```

```
if (42)
{|
```

To automatically get from the second-to-last to the last, you must have some way to trigger a reindent of the current from typing `{`.  This is provided by cc-derived modes, provided you have `electric-indent-mode` active.  To find out whether it will work, do `F1 k {` and make sure it's *not* bound to `self-insert-command`.  This has been broken in `csharp-mode` for some time, but should no longer be.  More discussion can be found on https://github.com/josteink/csharp-mode/issues/115 and the linked issues.

Comment: For class, if, for  etc structures this works like you explained, electric-indent-mode is active. Still only for methods this fails... The F1 k { gives out { runs the command c-electric-brace, which is an interactive compiled
Lisp function in ‘cc-cmds.el’.

It is bound to }, {.

(c-electric-brace ARG)

Insert a brace.

This strange behaviour applies also if I C-x h TAB.

Comment: EDIT: I might also add that on my home computer with spacemacs I don't have this problem.

Comment: Time for you to make sure both are using the latest version of csharp-mode and if they do, delete and reinstall to make sure.